# Using setTimeout in mouseenter and mouseleave events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$("#header .navigation li.menu-item-first a").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".sub-nav").css("display", "block");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".sub-nav").css("display", "none");
});
```

I don't want `.sub-nav` to disappear as soon as the user moves the mouse away.
How would I integrate `setTimeout` into these?

Comment: ...by doing it? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is also way to use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$("#header .navigation li.menu-item-first a").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".sub-nav").stop(true).css("display", "block"); //stop "animation" and clear queue
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".sub-nav").delay(1000).fadeOut(1);
});
```

[demo of usage](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rEnpe/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#header .navigation li.menu-item-first a").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".sub-nav").css("display", "block");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".sub-nav").css("display", "none");
    }, 1000);
});
```

Maybe?

Comment: You would want the `mouseenter` handler to cancel that timeout, if it exists, otherwise if the user moves their mouse out (tripping the timeout) and then back in within 1 second (or whatever the `setTimeout` delay is), the menu would show again with the `mouseenter` handler (even though it's already shown), but then hide when the timeout resolves even with the mouse on the menu.